# Delete Rows in specific columns based on values

Tags: excel, vba

I got quite a specific task that im not getting quite right, wondering if anyone could help me out.
In my code, I have a big table that gets updated monthly amongst my team, what I want to do is find the column header titled "RD" and then delete all the rows within that column containing the value "Ad-Hoc" (apart from the column header)

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr")

    Dim I As Long, finalRow As Long, L As Long
    
For L = tbl.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(1, L) = "RD" Then
                For I = finalRow To 2 Step -1
                If Range(L, I).Value = "Ad-Hoc" Then
            Range(L, I).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next I
    End If
    Next L

End Sub
```

wonder if anyone could help me with this and whether im on the right track. thanks

Comment: Use a filter and delete visible cells... no need to loop here. Also, `tbl.ListColumns("RD")` is the column in question, no need to "find" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete Rows in Table

- This will delete table rows (not worksheet rows).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteRowsBasedOnValue()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table_owssvr")
        Dim cNum As Long: cNum = .ListColumns("RD").Index
        Dim dRng As Range
        Dim lr As ListRow
        For Each lr In .ListRows
            If lr.Range.Columns(cNum).Value = "Ad-Hoc" Then
                buildRange dRng, lr.Range
            End If
        Next lr
    End With
    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
        dRng.Delete
    End If
End Sub

Sub buildRange( _
        ByRef BuiltRange As Range, _
        AddRange As Range)
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set BuiltRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set BuiltRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You need to use `tbl.ListColumns.Count` listobjects don't have a columns property.

You need to assign `finalRow` a value, and you have your row and column swapped looking for "Ad-Hoc"

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr")

Dim I As Long, finalRow As Long, L As Long
    
For L = tbl.ListColumns.Count To 1 Step -1 'tbl.columns will error
    If Cells(1, L) = "RD" Then
        finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, L).End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last row in column L
        For I = finalRow To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(I, L).Value = "Ad-Hoc" Then 'L is the column it goes second
                Cells(I, L).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next I
    End If
Next L
```

Using Autofilter

```
Sub delete_with_filter()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim delrange As Range
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr")

    With tbl
        .Range.AutoFilter .ListColumns("RD").Index, "Ad-Hoc"
        On Error GoTo errhandler
        Set delrange = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Not delrange Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            delrange.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter .ListColumns("RD").Index
        
    End With
errhandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1004
            Debug.Print "Exiting Sub, No Cells Found"
            tbl.Range.AutoFilter tbl.ListColumns("RD").Index
            Exit Sub
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot answers, but I will throw this one in for short and quick.  I tested and worked.

```
Sub DeleteTableRows()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr")
    
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=tbl.ListColumns("RD").Index, Criteria1:="Ad-Hoc"
    If tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > tbl.ListColumns.Count Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
     
    tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    
End Sub
```